# Receiving POST request with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ip-camera

I have an Axis M1011 camera which is set up to send a series of jpeg images as long as it is detecting motion, to a service (using HTTP POST). I'm building the service using node.js.

I'm successfully receiving POST requests with their headers, but I am having trouble saving the data in the body of the request. Here is the code:

```
function addEvent(req, res)
{
    var buffer = '';
    console.log(req.headers);
    req.on("data", function(chunk)
    {
        console.log("chunk received");
        buffer += chunk;
    });
    req.on("end", function()
    {
        console.log("saving file");
        fs.writeFile("./tmp/"+ new Date().getTime()+".jpg", buffer, function(error)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("saved");
                res.send("OK"); 
                res.end();
            }
        });

    });

}
```

On the console, I get this kind of output. Ofcourse, the content-length differs from file to file:

```
{ host: '192.168.0.100:8888',
  'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
  'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="file13-07-19_20-49-44-91"',
  'content-length': '18978' }
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
chunk received
saving file
saved
```

The problem is that I am getting one same, corrupted, file in the tmp folder which size is about 33KB, no matter how big is the image. What am I doing wrong with receiving these files?

Comment: did you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: To be honest, no. I've used node.js after and I think I actually made it to work, but at this exact case I have no idea what was wrong. Maybe the one existing answer has sense, but I didn't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the POST request to get the file that has been sent. When you submit a file in POST request, you wrap file meta data as well as data and send it to the server.

The server has to decode the request, and get the file. Simply saving the request won't do. You did not mention if you are using any web-server framework. It is better you use one like [express](https://npmjs.org/package/express) which does this for you. Express will parse the request, get the file object and save the file into temporary file.

Comment: Yes, I am using express. I have also tried with using the express body parser, but no luck because there the server stops responding after turning it on. It may be I'm using it wrong. How should that be done with express?

Comment: Actually I have to correct myself, the req.body is empty, although the bodyParser is used.